# Module and With do not work in some cases

Tags: scoping

I apologize if the title is too vague/general but I couldn't find a better one. I am trying to use either Module or With but it does not work if the object containing the local variables is defined outside of Module or With. Here is an example that does not work:

```
f = Cos[qx + qy];
With[{qy = qx},
f
]
```

which gives:

```
Cos[qx + qy]
```

but this obviously works:

```
With[{qy = qx},
Cos[qx + qy]
]
```

and gives:

```
Cos[2 qx]
```

What am I missing?
I could define f as a function and that would work. But I would like to understand why this scoping does not work while it works in other languages.

Comment: Try `With[{qy = qx}, Evaluate[f]]`

Comment: Thanks that works! Do you know why it doesn't work without the Evaluate?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it properly. You can use `Trace` to look at the evaluation process of both with and without `Evaluate`.

Comment: See [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/142) for extended discussion about `With`/`Module`/`Block` scoping.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This arises out of how Mathematica scopes variables. `With` and `Module` use lexical scoping, which is to say they scope the variables by name as they see them. `Block` uses dynamic scoping, which captures and resets the value of the `Symbol`.

This input might help explain it:

```
f = Cos[qx + qy];
Module[{qy = qx},
 {f, qy, Hold[qy]}
 ]

{Cos[qx + qy], qx, Hold[qy$113564]}
```

Every explicit instance of `qy` in the body has been renamed to `qy$113564` and that has been given the value `qx`. Then `f` is evaluated.

Because of this ordering the `qy` in `f` doesn't see the `Module` variable `qy$113564`.

On the other hand this will work:

```
Block[{qy = qx},
 {f, qy, Hold[qy]}
 ]

{Cos[2 qx], qx, Hold[qy]}
```

Because `Block` reassigns the value of `qy` directly without any renaming.

Finally, returning to your case at hand:

```
f = Cos[qx + qy];
With[{qy = qx},
 {f, qy, Hold[qy]}
 ]

{Cos[qx + qy], qx, Hold[qx]}
```

`With` injects the value `qx` anywhere it sees `qy` exactly by name in its body. `Evaluate` forces the body to have an explicit `qy` in it for `With` to see.

These different scoping constructs are very powerful and Leonid has a few nice posts on how they can be most effectively used.